Can't run command after pip install in Mac OS and zshrc
I'm trying to configure a new MacBook Pro from scratch. I've installed Xcode, iTerm2, Oh My Zsh and Tmux, just to inform.
I've also set aliases for pip and python from pip3 and python3.
which python 
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python
which pip        
pip: aliased to /usr/bin/pip

I managed to install a pip package that I need:
pip install keyring --index-url https://pypi.org/simple
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: keyring in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (25.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jaraco.classes in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from keyring) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jaraco.functools in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from keyring) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jaraco.context in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from keyring) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.11.4 in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from keyring) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.11.4->keyring) (3.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from jaraco.classes->keyring) (10.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.tarfile in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from jaraco.context->keyring) (1.2.0)

but when I try to
keyring get gitlab.com <your_token_name> &>/dev/null || keyring set gitlab.com <your_token_name>

I get:
keyring
zsh: command not found: keyring

And I don't know why. I tried to export PATH & PYTHONPATH but looks like it's not working.
What I am doing wrong or missing?
In my ~/.zshrc I have defined:
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH

 echo $PATH
 /Users/pablo.solar/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/bin:/Users/pablo.solar/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/utilities

but I can provide it fully
